# Rarefaction with specaccum in R

Tags: r, plot, vegan

I have a question concerning the `rarefaction` method in the `specaccum`fucntion in R.

I have the following dataset

```
Species1  Species2 Species3 ... Species75
10        20       5        ... 7
```

And I am trying to plot a curve with on the x-axis the amount of individuals and on the y-axis the amount of species (in the example above this should lead to 75).

I am trying to plot this as follows:

```
plot(specaccum(dataset, method="rarefaction", xvar="individuals"))
```

But I get nothing.
Can someone help me?

Thank you very much

Victor D.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try creating an object I used chao1 method, put what you prefer, and after plot separately

sac <- specaccum(dataset,method ="rarefaction", gamma = "chao1")

plot(sac, add = FALSE, random = FALSE, ci = 2, ci.type = c("polygon"), col = par("fg"),  xvar = c( "individuals"))

See http://127.0.0.1:12380/library/vegan/html/specaccum.html to be sure

Comment: Hey
I get a plot but there is nothing on it, I think there is a problem with the xvar=c("individuals"), I used the term 'individuals' to indicate that the plot should be based on the values in my example above. How do u make that R uses these values to construct the x-axis, because there is not really a column that is named 'individuals'? Thanks Victor